# Dynamic Query Generation is not working with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute following SQL statement :

```
USE[Northwind] 
declare @MainQuery varchar(255),
@WhereClause varchar(255)


Select @WhereClause = 'where CustomerId =ALFKI'

Select @MainQuery ='Select * from Customers '+@WhereClause

execute(@MainQuery)
```

But getting the error ,

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'ALFKI'.

What is wrong ?

Comment: i think there was data mismatch in the where condition

Comment: I realize this is using the northwind database and as such is likely a learning process here but this query is downright scary. You need to read up on sql injection because this is a textbook example of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALFKI is being treated as if it is a column name.  Your generated sql will look like this:

```
select * from Customers where CustomerID = ALFKI
```

What you want is your code to look like this:

```
select * from Customers where CustomerID = 'ALFKI'
```

To achieve this, change your where clause generator to this:

```
Select @WhereClause = 'where CustomerId = ''ALFKI'' '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select @WhereClause = 'where CustomerId =''ALFKI'''
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation on why and how your code snippet does answer the OP question